# Are arrays const datatypes

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        char a[]="aaa";
        char *b="bbb";
        strcpy(a,"cc");
        printf("%s",a);
        strcpy(b,"dd");
        printf("%s",b);
        return 0;
}
```

We could not modify the contents of the array but the above program does not show any compile time error.When run it printed cc and terminated. The contents of the array i think will get stored in the read only section of the data segment and so its not possible to change the value of array as its a const.But here in the above program the value got changed to cc and the program terminated.The value got changed here why is it so.Please help me understand.

Comment: Please provide the output. `a` should be modifiable, while `b` should not be.

Comment: Is this on an embedded system where there is actual ROM?  If not, you can probably change stuff at will in RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hypothetical memory map showing how the string literals, array, and pointer all relate to each other:

```
Item              Address            0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----              -------            ----  ----  ----  ----
"aaa"             0x00040000          'a'   'a'   'a'  0x00
"bbb"             0x00040004          'b'   'b'   'b'  0x00
"cc"              0x00040008          'c'   'c'   0x00 ???
"dd"              0x0004000C          'd'   'd'   0x00 ???
...
  a               0x08000000          'a'   'a'   'a'  0x00
  b               0x08000004          0x00  0x04  0x00 0x00
```

This is the situation at line 6 in your code, after `a` and `b` have been declared and initialized.  The string literals `"aaa"`, `"bbb"`, `"cc"`, and `"dd"` all reside somewhere in memory such that they exist over the lifetime of the program.  They are stored as arrays of `char` (`const char` in C++).  Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal (in the case of this hypothetical, attempting to write to any memory location starting with 0x0004) invokes undefined behavior.  Some platforms store string literals in read-only memory, some store them in writable memory, but in all cases, they should be treated *as though* they are unwritable.

The object `a` is an array of `char`, and it has been initialized with the *contents* of the string literal `"aaa"`.  The object `b` is a pointer to `char`, and it has been initialized with the *address* of the string literal `"bbb"`.  In the line

```
strcpy(a, "cc");
```

you're copying the contents of the string literal `"cc"` to `a`; after the line is executed, your memory map looks like this:

```
Item              Address            0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----              -------            ----  ----  ----  ----
"aaa"             0x00040000          'a'   'a'   'a'  0x00
"bbb"             0x00040004          'b'   'b'   'b'  0x00
"cc"              0x00040008          'c'   'c'   0x00 ???
"dd"              0x0004000C          'd'   'd'   0x00 ???
...
  a               0x08000000          'c'   'c'   0x00 0x00
  b               0x08000004          0x00  0x04  0x00 0x00
```

So when you print `a` to standard output, you should see the string `cc`.  Note: `printf` is buffered, so it's possible that output may not be written to the terminal immediately - either add a newline character to the format string (`printf("%s\n", a);`) or call `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` to make sure all your output shows up.

In line 9, you attempt to copy the contents of the string literal `"dd"` to the location pointed to by `b`; unfortunately, `b` points to another string literal, which as mentioned above invokes undefined behavior.  At this point, your program could literally do anything from run as expected to crash outright to anything in between.  This could be part of the reason you only see the output for `cc`.

Answer (score 3):

Array is not a constant datatype but a literal string like "aaa" is. You cannot modify it's content.

Comment: "You cannot modify it's content" does not necessarily mean that it is "constant". In fact, at the type level string literals in C are not `const`. They are just "non-modifiable". They are "non-modifiable" because the standard explicitly says so.

Answer (score 1):

You have several arrays in your program. Some of them are modifiable, others are not. So, your original question ("Are arrays const datatypes?") is not really answerable in any meaningful way.

String literals (like `"aaa"`) are arrays, but they are not modifiable. Note that in C language string literals are not really `const` (For example array `"aaa"`, has type `char[4]`, not `const char[4]`). However, it is still explicitly prohibited by the language to attempt to modify string literals. The compiler is not required to catch such attempts. Also, no run-time error is guaranteed to happen when you make such an attempt. The behavior is simply *undefined*. When you do `strcpy(b,"dd")`, you attempt to modify a non-modifiable array - the behavior is undefined. Anything can happen.

As for the ordinary array `a` in your code sample, it is declared as modifiable. So, you can modify it as much as you want. When you do `strcpy(a, "cc")`, you copy string `"cc"` into your  array `a`. So, that exactly what you observe in your experiment whe you print the content of `a`. Nothing unusual here.

Answer (score 1):

`char* != char[]`!

In this case, `a` is a buffer to a writeable area which is first filled with the content of a literal string, which is stored in a read-only area, while `b` is a pointer which directly points to a read-only area! Here is a sample code to help you understand :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define literal "test"

int main() {
  char a[] = literal
  char b[] = literal;
  char* c = literal;
  char* d = literal;

  printf("%s (%p)\n", a, a);
  printf("%s (%p)\n", b, b);
  printf("%s (%p)\n", c, c);
  printf("%s (%p)\n", d, d);

  return 42;
}
```

By executing this code, you'll see that even if all 4 string printed are the same, `a` and `b` addresses different areas in memory, while `c` and `d` point to a unique third area adress. In addition, you should see a big difference in address range between the first two and the last one : here, the location in *different areas of memory (read/write and read-only)* is made obvious.

**Edit** : just to insist, a fifth printf (`printf("%s (%p)\n", literal, literal);`) would print the same than `c` and `d` lines.

Comment: @Chris : woups, you're right! Haven't used C for a long time ^^'. Will correct!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not const datatypes, but literals are. The string literals "aaa" and "bbb" cannot be modified (or they can, but the result is undefined).

As pointed by Paul R, `char a[] = "aaa";` is fine because it will use the string literal to initialize an array (which as I mentioned aren't const datatypes). It's `char *b = "bbb";` the problem here, since you later try to modify the contents of the string literal itself, and not a copy.

Comment: No - `char a[] = "aaa";` is fine, it's `char *b = "bbb";` that's the problem here. a can be modified but b can't - it's implicitly const.

Comment: you are right paul.I havent allocated memory for the pointer.

Comment: @Angus: it's not because of memory allocation - b is a string literal, which is implicitly const, and is typically (but not necessarily) stored in a read-only segment.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is pointing toward a string `bbb` which is stored in read-only memory.which cannot be changed by `strcpy()` or anything.